# Different version of ODP for connecting Oracle

Tags: .net-4.0, ado.net, oracle11g, odp.net

I am using **Oracle Client** to connect oracle from **.net**. Now I since Oracle-Client is depicted by Microsoft. So I wanted to use ODP instead.

I have searched and found there are different [versions of ODP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/newfeatures-084113.html) available. I am just confiscated.

Reasons:-

1. Do the different version (ODP) are for different dot net framework
2. Or the different version of ODP is for different version of Oracle.

I am using Oracle 11.2 G and .net framework 4. Which version of ODP should I use.
Further If my database is moved to oracle 12C will I need to change my code (Different ODP).

Answer (score 0):

The version number you see for an ODP.NET dll is a combination of the .NET framework version (2 or 4) and the Oracle client version. By Oracle client, we mean the entire stack needed to connect to Oracle including the networking components.

You can typically use an Oracle client vs a database that is up to two major releases earlier. So in your case, go ahead and download ODP.NET 12.1. It will work fine against an 11g database. Any download of ODP.NET will contain versions for both .NET 2.x and .NET 4.x

Your next concerns are as follows: Unmanaged vs Managed? And if Unmanaged, 32-bit vs 64 bit.